# How to access, edit & save the text of a list inside another list?

Tags: python, csv

```py
import csv

#!pip install tweet-preprocessor
import preprocessor as p

p.set_options(p.OPT.MENTION,p.OPT.URL, p.OPT.EMOJI)
f = open('April 9.csv', 'r')
d = [i for i in csv.reader(f) ]

for i in d:
  print(p.clean(d[i]))
```

`April 9.csv` is a csv file having only one column of text but up to 4000 rows.
`clean()` takes in a string, but according to what i have here, the program is
just returning a list to `clean()`. I want to pass a string to `clean()` which corresponds to the rows of the csv file and consequently save it as a csv
file.

Comment: Can you add the sample of what the program is returning exactly?

Comment: `csv.reader` returns a _list_ of items, so `[i for i in csv.reader(f)]` is creating a list-of-lists, and each sublist consists of only one item. Saying you have a csv with only one column is almost an oxymoron since there are no values to separate — meaning there's not much point in reading it with the `csv` module at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for Martinaeu's Comment**

*Using readline/write*

Just write each cleaned line to your new file as you read it from the CSV:

```
#!pip install tweet-preprocessor
import preprocessor as p

p.set_options(p.OPT.MENTION,p.OPT.URL, p.OPT.EMOJI)

with open('April 9.csv', 'r') as rf, open('New File.csv', 'w+') as wf:
    for line in rf:
        wf.write(p.clean(line))
```

---

*Using csv (for the sake of explanation)*

`d = [i for i in csv.reader(f)]` is creating a list of lists because you are working with 2 dimensions in a CSV, rows and columns. If you had a CSV like

```
A1, A2
B1, B2
C1, C2
...
```

then `d` would contain

```
[
  ['A1', 'A2'],
  ['B1', 'B2'],
  ['C1', 'C2'], 
  ...
]
```

In your specific case, `d` is

```
[
  ['<Row 1 value>'],
  ['<Row 2 value>'],
  ['<Row 3 value>'],
  ...
  ['<Row 4000 value>']
]
```

You need to change your list comprehension to only `clean()` the single column's value

```
d = [p.clean(i[0]) for i in csv.reader(f)] # Option 1: 1-D list
```

**or**

```
d = [[p.clean(i[0])] for i in csv.reader(f)] # Option 2: 2-D list
```

The first option prevents you from storing a 2-D list since you're only working with a single column, but note that `writerow()` below takes in a list of columns to write, so you can go either route.

Once you have the list you want to store, you can then write it to another CSV file like so:

```py
with open('New CSV.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in d:
        writer.writerow([i]) # If you use option 1
        # writer.writerow(i) - If you use option 2
```